# Using Numeric.Integration.TanhSinh for N-dimensional integration

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am using [Numeric.Integration.TanhSinh](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/integration-0.1.1/docs/Numeric-Integration-TanhSinh.html) for numerical integration in Haskell. This defines a function

```
parTrap :: (Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double -> [Result]
```

where the first argument is the 1-dimensional function to be integrated, then upper and lower bounds. I have a wrapper which transforms this function as

```
ttrap f xmin xmax = (ans, err)
   where
      res = absolute 1e-6 $ parTrap f xmin xmax
      ans = result res
      err = errorEstimate res
```

To integrate a 2-dimensional function, I can use

```
 ttrap2 f y1 y2 g1 g2 = ttrap h y1 y2 -- f ylower yupper (fn for x lower) (fn for x upper) 
       where
           h y = fst $ ttrap (flip f y) (g1 y) (g2 y)

ttrap2_fixed f y1 y2 x1 x2 = ttrap2 f y1 y2 (const x1) (const x2)
```

The idea of `ttrap2_fixed` is that I can now do a double integral where the function is (Double -> Double -> Double), and bounds are `y1 y2 x1 x2`.

Using this pattern, I can define higher order integration functions

```
ttrap3_fixed :: (Double -> Double -> Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
ttrap3_fixed f z1 z2 y1 y2 x1 x2 = fst $ ttrap h z1 z2
  where
    h z  = fst $ ttrap2_fixed (f z)  x1 x2 y1 y2


ttrap4_fixed :: (Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
ttrap4_fixed f w1 w2 z1 z2 y1 y2 x1 x2 = fst $ ttrap h w1 w2
  where
    h w  = ttrap3_fixed (f w) z1 z2 x1 x2 y1 y2


ttrap5_fixed :: (Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
ttrap5_fixed f u1 u2 w1 w2 z1 z2 y1 y2 x1 x2 = fst $ ttrap h u1 u2
  where
    h u  = ttrap4_fixed (f u) w1 w2 z1 z2 x1 x2 y1 y2
```

However, I would like to integrate a function of type

```
f :: [Double] -> Double
```

with the idea being that the dimensionality of the function can vary within the program. Ideally, I would like a function with type

```
int_listfn :: ([Double] -> Double) -> [(Double, Double)] -> Double
```

where I can integrate the multidimensional function over a list of tuples of bounds. As part of this, it seems like I need to use something like continuation passing style to construct the integrator function, but this is where I am getting stuck. Thanks in advance.

---

An example of a `f` that I would like to integrate would be something like

```
> let f [x,y,z] = x**3.0 * sin(y) + (1.0/z)
```

Consider bounds

```
> let bounds = [(1.0,2.0),(2.0,4.0), (0.0,3.0)]
> int_listfn f bounds
```

This should be equivalent to calculating
[image]

---

EDIT: Adding another example function

```
f1 :: Double -> Double
f1 x = 1.0 * x


fn_maker :: [Double -> Double] -> ([Double] -> Double)
fn_maker inlist = myfn
  where
    myfn xlist = product $ zipWith (\f x -> f x) inlist xlist


m = 4

f_list = fn_maker (replicate f1 m)
```

`f_list` has type `[Double] -> Double` and is equivalent to `f x y z w = x * y * z * w`. I thought that the type `[Double] -> Double` would be appropriate because the dimensionality of the function, `m`, is a parameter. Perhaps I need to change the design.

---

**List function to curried functions**, @fizruk I have been using this in my code and seems to work, although I need to keep track of which function to call based on the size of the bounds list.

```
static_1 :: ([Double] -> Double) -> (Double -> Double)
static_1 f = f'
  where
    f' x = f [x]


static_2 :: ([Double] -> Double) -> (Double -> Double -> Double)
static_2 f = f'
  where
    f' x y = f [x,y]


static_3 :: ([Double] -> Double) -> (Double -> Double -> Double -> Double)
static_3 f = f'
  where
    f' x y z = f [x,y,z]


static_4 :: ([Double] -> Double) -> (Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double)
static_4 f = f'
  where
    f' x y z w = f [x,y,z,w]


static_5 :: ([Double] -> Double) -> (Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double)
static_5 f = f'
  where
    f' x y z w u = f [x,y,z,w,u]


int_listfn :: ([Double] -> Double) -> [(Double, Double)] -> Double
int_listfn f bounds  
  | f_dim == 1 = fst $ ttrap (static_1 f) (fst (bounds !! 0)) (snd (bounds !! 0))
  | f_dim == 2 = fst $ ttrap2_fixed  (static_2 f) (fst (bounds !! 0)) (snd (bounds !! 0)) (fst (bounds !! 1)) (snd (bounds !! 1))
  | f_dim == 3 = ttrap3_fixed  (static_3 f) (fst (bounds !! 0)) (snd (bounds !! 0)) (fst (bounds !! 1)) (snd (bounds !! 1)) (fst (bounds !! 2)) (snd (bounds !! 2))
  | f_dim == 4 = ttrap4_fixed  (static_4 f) (fst (bounds !! 0)) (snd (bounds !! 0)) (fst (bounds !! 1)) (snd (bounds !! 1)) (fst (bounds !! 2)) (snd (bounds !! 2)) (fst (bounds !! 3)) (snd (bounds !! 3))
  | f_dim == 5 = ttrap5_fixed  (static_5 f) (fst (bounds !! 0)) (snd (bounds !! 0)) (fst (bounds !! 1)) (snd (bounds !! 1)) (fst (bounds !! 2)) (snd (bounds !! 2)) (fst (bounds !! 3)) (snd (bounds !! 3)) (fst (bounds !! 3)) (snd (bounds !! 3))
  | otherwise = error "Unsupported integral size"
  where
    f_dim = length bounds
```

Comment: Have you tried to use type classes to be able to integrate any function `f :: Intergrable r => r` with instances for `Double` and `Intergrable r => Double -> r`? I mean the similar trick to that exploited to make [`printf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html) polyvariadic?

Comment: Can't you define `f_list x y z w = product (map f1 [x, y, z, w])`? Or `product (zipWith ($) (repeat f1) [x, y, z, w])`? Both definition state precisely which number of arguments they take, but are "operating on list" `[x, y, z, w]`.

Comment: Yes, I could define it in that way, but if the `m` is a parameter in the code that is set, say as a command line argument by the user, then I would need definitions for every possible value of `m`, up to some `mMax`, right? I was hoping to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Though theoretically you might use existential types to hide the arity of a function, I think you simply should not use `[Double] -> Double` functions.

Comment: Agreed. I will have to rethink my design a bit. Anyway, thank you for the discussion and solution.

Comment: If you're interested in another solution you can use my [cubature library](https://github.com/stla/cubature). Or [cuba](https://github.com/stla/cuba) but I think cubature is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The idea

For convenience I introduce these type aliases:

```
type Res   = (Double, Double)
type Bound = (Double, Double)
```

Let's have a closer look at the types of `ttrap_fixedN`:

```
ttrap :: (Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double -> Res
ttrap_fixed2 :: (Double -> Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Res
```

Obviously, we can pair bounds to get a shorter and cleaner version:

```
ttrap :: (Double -> Double) -> Bound -> Res
ttrap_fixed2 :: (Double -> Double -> Double) -> Bound -> Bounds -> Res
```

Furthermore, we can collect `Bounds` together for `N` > `1`:

```
ttrap_fixed2 :: (Double -> Double -> Double) -> (Bound, Bound) -> Res
ttrap_fixed3 :: (Double -> Double -> Double -> Double) -> (Bound, Bound, Bound) -> Res
```

Notice how we made all `ttrap_fixedN` functions to take precisely 2 arguments. Also notice that the type of the second argument (the arity of tuple with `Bound`s) depends on the first (the arity of function to integrate).

Now it should be clear that a general `ttrap_fixed` function would depend on the arity of given function and we need type class to implement that kind of polymorphism. Besided `integrate` method (this is the general `ttrap_fixed`) that class would need an [*associated type synonym*](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-families.html) for the second argument:

```
class Integrable r where
  type Bounds r :: *
  integrate :: r -> Bounds r -> Res
```

### Solution sketch

We are going to need following extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Numeric.Integration.TanhSinh
```

Here's the only function from the question I'll use:

```
ttrap :: (Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double -> Res
ttrap f xmin xmax = (ans, err)
   where
      res = absolute 1e-6 $ parTrap f xmin xmax
      ans = result res
      err = errorEstimate res
```

Define `Integrable` type class:

```
class Integrable r where
  type Bounds r :: *
  integrate :: r -> Bounds r -> Res
```

And it's instances

```
instance Integrable Double where
  type Bounds Double = ()
  integrate x _ = (x, 0)

instance Integrable r => Integrable (Double -> r) where
  type Bounds (Double -> r) = (Bound, Bounds r)
  integrate f ((xmin, xmax), args) = ttrap g xmin xmax
    where
      g x = fst $ integrate (f x) args
```

Go test it:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let f :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
      f x y z = x ** 3.0 * sin(y) + (1.0/z)
      zbounds = (1.0, 2.0)
      ybounds = (2.0, 4.0)
      xbounds = (0.0, 3.0)
      res = integrate f (xbounds, (ybounds, (zbounds, ())))
  print res -- prints (8.9681929657648,4.732074732061164e-10)
```

### Currying `Bounds`

As you might have noticed, we now have not very convenient nested tuples for `Bound`s. It would be nice if `integrate f` would return a curried function, such as:

```
integrate (*) :: Bound -> Bound -> Res
```

instead of

```
integrate (*) :: (Bound, (Bound, ())) -> Res
```

Unfortunately, I failed to find any *simple* way to refactor `Integrable` to allow that. However, we can solve this issue with another typeclass hackery. The idea is to introduce a polymorhic `curryBounds`:

```
class CurryBounds bs where
  type Curried bs a :: *
  curryBounds :: (bs -> a) -> Curried bs a
```

The instances are straightforward:

```
instance CurryBounds () where
  type Curried () a = a
  curryBounds f = f ()

instance CurryBounds bs => CurryBounds (b, bs) where
  type Curried (b, bs) a = b -> Curried bs a
  curryBounds f = \x -> curryBounds (\xs -> f (x, xs))
```

Now we can define a nicer version of `integrate`:

```
integrate' :: (Integrable r, CurryBounds (Bounds r)) => r -> Curried (Bounds r) Res
integrate' = curryBounds . integrate
```

### Example

```
>>> let f x y z = x**3.0 * sin(y) + (1.0/z) :: Double
>>> integrate' f (0, 3) (2, 4) (1, 2)
(8.9681929657648,4.732074732061164e-10)
```

Comment: I don't like 2 things in this solution: `Integrable Double` which is not actually used (except for typechecking) and nested tuples of bounds.

Comment: First, thank you for the detailed answer. I realized that by defining my function as `f :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double` then this makes sense. However, what I am worried about is being able to take the dimensionality as a parameter (most likely between 1 and 10) and have a general purpose way of integrating them.

Comment: @stevejb- his answer will take arbitrary dimensionality, not as a param, but (and this is the beautiful part to me), it will determine this dimensionality at compile-time implicitly from the funciton type.

Comment: @jamshidh I added a further example to my question. I can construct a function of type ([Double] -> Double) where the "length" of the list is a runtime parameter.

Comment: @stevejb- I'm just not clear on why you don't like this answer....  Part of me would be happy to play with your approach and grab the 500 points bounty, but I am hesitant to bring myself to work this out in a complicated way when such a clean solution already exists....

Comment: @jamshidh @stevejb there are still problems outlined in the first comment. Besides there is an unanswered question about how to generate `n`-ary function given `n`. The latter should probably be asked as a separate question though.

Comment: @jamshidh I really like the answer. I just wanted to make sure I understand, @fizruk's answser works for any function of type f :: Double -> Double -> (... more Double -> ... ) -> Double. I see that. What I am wondering is how to integrate the `f_list` function as I defined my edit to the example code, especially when `m` is a parameter given at runtime by the user.

Comment: @fizruk I thought that the statement which defines `f_list` is essentially generating an n-ary function, but rather than n separate arguments, as a list of size n?

Comment: @stevejb yeah, I was talking about generating a curried function with `n` separate arguments.

Comment: @fizruk I added some code that I have been using which does that, but it only works for fixed sizes.

Comment: @stevejb I've managed to fix the issue with nested tuples of bounds, see update to the answer. I also tried to explain solution in more details.

Answer (score 1):

Fizruk's answer seems to be correct (although I haven't fact checked the details)....  But I thought I should add a complementary set of comments that explain why what you are trying to do won't work.

The function type to integrate has type

```
[Double]->Double
```

This doesn't quite do what you want it to do.  You want to f to have a preset domain dimensionality, but in the world of Haskell the type signature you gave would actually take in any number of values....  The following would be a valid consistent definition of f

```
f [] = 1.0
f [x] = x+1
f [x, y] = x+y
```

If you just passed this value into in integration function, it would have no way to know which line in the definition you meant to specify  (you could add this dimensionality in as an extra parameter, but it is kind of overkill to use a mechanism that can take an array of arbitrary length then use a param to fix the length....  Although considering the alternatives, this might be the best solution).

You could use tuples instead.  This would solve the dimensionality question, but writing code that works across arbitrary length tuples is hard, and generally needs some GHC extension.

I like Fizruk's approach, it is clean and very sleek, and you get to use fully curried functions as they were intended to be used....  The only downside is that you will have to learn slightly more advanced Haskell to understand how it works (although perhaps that is an advantage for you).

---

@SteveJB pointed out that the dimensionality is given as the length of the bounds param (an obvious fact that I had missed)....  But I still think that the array approach has some problems.

First, I would naturally think to use recursion here (ie- to integrate an in N dimensions, sum the N-1 dimensions at spaced slices), but that is really hard to do with an array function and sized bounds.  Once you peeled off the outermost bounds, the size would change and the wrong "subfunction" in f would be used.  You could solve this by pulling out the size of the bounds on a wrapper function, but the internal function would need a dimensionality param, anyway :).  Also, it isn't so easy to "curry" a function of the type [Double]->Double in the way you are using it.  Ultimately you might have to pass in all the slice positions.

Again, I want to stress that you *could* make this work, but it would probably be messier than what Fizruk did.

Comment: I suppose I had intended the length of the list of bounds to signify the length of the implicit list in f. I agree that anything that helps me learn more haskell helps me.

Comment: I am thinking that perhaps I can define a type that is essentially the a function [Double] -> Double plus some dimensionality information. This way, I can essentially mimic partial application, but retain the information of "how many unapplied dimensions are left?"

Comment: I've added to my answer....  As per your last comment, it could be done, although it would probably be easier if you don't use parTrap, just sum up at the points.  I still stand by my comment though, that this would be less clean that what Fizruk did. :)